# How do I set the KyyMD application open as a maximized window?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to set my `KivyMD` application open as a maximized window and it should be opened in in the middle of the screen. And should not be possible to resize the window. I have written a code to disable resizing.

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
```

But I haven't an idea to open the application as maximized window. So, how to do that? Please help me.

Comment: Did you try `Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 1)`?

Comment: Yes sir. I tried that method. But then the window becomes a full screen. Also the close and minimize buttons are hidden with the tittle bar (Not KivyMD tittle bar, Windows default tittle bar). If the title bar can also be displayed in full screen mode,  that's perfect, sir.

Comment: Okay sir. Then I thought fullscreen mode was good. Yeah, It's Great. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution to this problem is to first get your screen size using the `pyautogui` module, and then set the window size to it, something like this:

```
import pyautogui 
# This module comes with Windows' standard Python package
# You might wanna install it manually if you are not using Windows

width, height = pyautogui.size()
Config.set('graphics', 'width', str(width))
Config.set('graphics', 'height', str(height))
```

Edit: So basically I was messing around trying to find an answer for another question, and then I figured out how to maximize the window while still having the titlebar, exactly what the author wanted:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.maximize()
```

Comment: But even in this method the tittle bar and close button are not visible.

Comment: well, what about trying this: `Window.size = (width, height)` instead of the 2 `Config` lines

Comment: Okay. Then I thought fullscreen mode was good. Yeah, It's Great. Thank you

Comment: So I don't know if it notifies you when I edit my answer or not so I will just leave my comment here asking you to check the edit :)

Comment: Thank you very much, worked for me
Window.maximize()